# SocialEngine Hooks that triggered on friend list update

Tags: events, plugins, module, hook, socialengine

Is there any hook that related to friends list update i.e. when i add/remove friends the hook should trigger?
or is the any documentation on creating new hooks or any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own hook in the Socialengine. There is not hook for the firendship in the socialengine.

Comment: Is there any documentation for creating new hook as i am new to SocialEngine?

Comment: I wanted to create it through my SocialEngine plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the complete list of hooks [here](http://social-engine-tutorials.blogspot.in/2012/03/complete-list-of-social-engine-4-hooks.html) and example of how to write a hook in SocialEngine [here](http://social-engine-tutorials.blogspot.in/2012/03/social-engine-4-hook-example.html)

Comment: it will be good if you add this as a comment or answer with sample code.